# Signed into my one drive on someone else's computer and now they have access to my work files and can save their own files in my work account. WTF?

Tags: ms-office, microsoft, onedrive

I have signed on my work OneDrive account on someone else's computer. I know I had logged out. Yet for some reasons they still have access to all of my One Drive files and the recent save as list makes it possible for them to save their own files to my work account. WTF is going on. F Microsoft. Anyone know what is going on? Please help. Thanks! I am on Mac.

Comment: It cached your credential.  Did you delete it out of the keychain?

Comment: Change your password immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your work OneDrive admin may be needed to intervene depending on how they set up the service. Your password is only used when the secure token generated to authorize API access to the service needs to be regenerated, so you may need to block that client and/or force invalidation of all tokens for your account.

The sign out option typically is very reliable for us, but perhaps the second dialog asking you to delete the files or clean up the files was blocked by another window. Did you clean out all the locally cached files and empty trash before leaving the computer? If not, you might need to visit that computer again even after you get it blocked from participating in ongoing sync with your online drive to finish securing your work files